# Add to source control fails to show activity list if folder name starts with capital letter

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

Today we faced weird issue in Clearcase UCM.

We were trying to add a folder named "Common" (which has many subfolders and file elements).

When we click on add to source control , it doesn't show up activity list box. (it is displaying as if we were trying to add to source control in base clearcase).

When we cancel it ,it threw exception and changed the folder name first as small letter (common). If we try to add this to source control, It displayed activity list.(like normal UCM add to source control dialog).

We checked the case preservation check box in cc.cpl then restarted the services. but still we faced the same issue.

We are using latest clearcase and OS is Windows 7. I am not sure why this occurs . It stopped us to add source control with the name "Common".

what could be the issue ? If you have faced this and solved it , please guide me.

Comment: What a `cleartool ls` in the parent directory of "Common" shows? Any weird status? (like eclipsed, disputed checkout, ...). Are you using a snapshot or dynamic view? Do you reproduce the issue in any UCM view?

Answer (score 1):

The usual recommendation, whenever strange errors are happening though the GUI, is to fallback to the CLI.

See:

- "[To add elements (files and directories) to source control from the command line](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.hlp.doc/cc_main/to_add_src_control.htm)"
- [`cleartool mkelem`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mkelem.htm)

You can do:

```
# go to the parent directory of Common
cd <view/path/to/Common>/..
# check there is a current activity set
cleartool lsact -cact
# checkout the parent directory
cleartool checkout -nc .
# add to source control Common (not its content, just the directory)
cleartool mkelem –nc -ci -ptime –eltype directory
# checkin the parent directory
cleartool checkin -nc .
```